# How to delete a branch when using git review

Tags: git, openstack, gerrit, git-review

I have trouble with gerrit in OpenStack and really need your help! I created a new branch and used git-review as shown in this link:

http://docs.openstack.org/infra/manual/developers.html

Now I would like to delete the branch so that it no longer displays in OpenStack review.For example, I want to remove the following link in OpenStack.

https://review.openstack.org/#/c/XXXXXXX/

Please let me know how I can do it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a branch, it's a change. You can "abandon" this change in the Gerrit UI. This is similar to closing an issue in an issue tracker (it will not be removed, but others don't see it as open for review).

Comment: Thank @Stephen. I have one more question. I created a new branch. But unfortunately, I removed it with the command: 

"git branch -d the_local_branch".  Actually, the change still appears in Gerrit UI. Now, I want to recover this branch so that I can continue to work on it. Please let me know how I can do. Thanks

Comment: There is a link in the UI to checkout the change that you pushed (please familiarize a bit with Gerrit). If my answer helped, please mark it as correct using the check mark.